# ID1024 The configuration property value is not valid error in Azure WebSite

Tags: azure, x509certificate, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to consume the certificate uploaded in azure website(not webrole) in my web app using following config

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<!-- Service Configuration -->
<service>
  <serviceCertificate>
    <certificateReference findValue="2696C50B72CB368AEB11DE3B23CD226252A1BFD" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>       
  </serviceCertificate>
  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
</service>
```

Code works fine on local system. But I am recieving error when deployed to azure website.

```
ID1024 The configuration property value is not valid 
ID1025 Cannot find a unique certificate that matches the criteria
```

I then tried to browse all the certificates in my azure website(using code). But the certificate list does not contain my uploaded certificate.

Certificate is uploaded and can be seen in azure portal.
Custom domain is mapped and the uploaded certficiate is used against the domain.
But somehow my web app is unable to find the certificate. I tried all possible combination of StoreName and StoreLocation but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some confusion on what the certificates you upload via the Configure tab for Websites are used for.  Currently the certificates loaded there are ONLY used for SSL.

When looking at the little help icon next to the certificates section on the configure tab the tooltip states the following:

"*This section lets you manage SSL certificates that you can bind to your custom domain names. Binding an SSL certificate to your custom domain name will allow your end users to access your site over HTTPS.*"

Windows Azure Web Sites exist at a process level, meaning that they can be started up on one machine but move around as the processes go up and down.  If you aren't familiar with this I'd suggest reading up on how the hosting model works for Web Sites.  Here is an article that covers it: [Windows Azure Web Sites - A New Hosting Model for Windows Azure](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/windows-azure-websites-%E2%80%93-a-new-hosting-model-for-windows-azure/) (full disclosure: I wrote the article).

Loading the certificate here I do not believe adds the certificate to any of the stores on the machines your web site runs on.  Windows Azure would need to ensure that the cert is always on the machine the site is deployed to and since this is only at a process level and can change frequently (unless you are using standard) it doesn't make sense.  The SSL certs are handled differently and as far as I know aren't really deployed to each machine.

As far as I know in order for you to load a certificate and use it you'll either need to look at a web role where loaded certs from the portal ARE placed into the store on the VM or look to see if you can load the certificate manually in code and ship the cert as content on your site (which seems a little less secure to me). I could just be overlooking an option though.